# Is the sticky bit not used in current file systems

Tags: linux, inode, ext2

Can I safely conclude that the sticky bit is not used in current file sysems and reuse the bit for my own purpose.

Comment: NO, YOU MAY NOT!! And, if I could set a larger, redder font, I would :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot assume that.  It's not true for directories.  You can make the narrower assumption that it's true for non-directory files.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it's currently unused for non-directories, *others have undoubtedly had the same idea* and are probably currently using the sticky bit for their own nefarious purposes.  The sticky bit is *not* meant for arbitrary user-defined marks on a file.  Use extended attributes instead!